# Crear archivo nuevo al hacer click en boton

Tags: php

Crear un archivo de texto cada vez que de *click* en el botón guardar, y que dentro de este se guarde lo que escriba en un *textarea*

Osea si presiono 3 veces el botón guardar se debe de crear un archivo teniendo asi:

> archivo1.txt primer click
>
> archivo2.txt segundo click
>
> archivo3.txt tercer click, etc, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este codigo:

```
 if(isset($_POST["txtareainst"]))
 {
         if($_POST["txtareainst"])  
         {    
             $contenido=$_POST["txtareainst"];
             $archivo='D:instruccion.txt';
             $file = fopen($archivo, 'ab') or die ();            
             fwrite ($file, $contenido.PHP_EOL);
             fclose($file);
             echo "He recibido en el archivo.php: ".$_POST["txtareainst"];
         }
         else
         {echo "He recibido un campo vacio";}
 }
```

Comment: agrega tu codigo actural, de tu boton guardar y de tu php

Comment: ya he añadido el codigo que tengo gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Realizar este paso de ir creando archivos de forma dinámica , una opción sería usar *Sesiones* para almacenar el contador , y algunas validaciones adicionales como el Método recibido *POST* , el valor del *TextArea* para luego escribir los datos.

**Ejemplo (index.php)**

```
<form  method="POST">
   <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar">
</form>

/* PHP*/
session_start(); /* Iniciamos Sessión*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['cont'])) $_SESSION['cont']=0;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ /* Validamos el Método*/
    if(isset($_POST['textarea'])){ /* Validamos el TextArea*/
        if(trim($_POST['textarea'])!=''){/* Validamos que no esté vacío*/
            $valor = $_POST['textarea'];
            $archivo = fopen("Archivo".$_SESSION['cont'].".txt", "w");
            $_SESSION['cont']=$_SESSION['cont']+1; /* Incrementamos el contador*/
            fwrite($archivo, $valor);
            fclose($archivo);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Si desea Reiniciar el Contador podría emplear un segundo archivo `PHP` *(reiniciar.php)* para realizar el `session_destroy()` , en su archivo principal donde está el formulario crearía un enlace donde apuntará al segundo archivo `PHP`

```
<a href="reiniciar.php">Reiniciar Contador</a>
```

En el archivo `reiniciar.php` tendría solo tres líneas para cerrar la sesión y redireccionar al archivo donde está el `form`

**reiniciar.php**

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
```

> Este ejemplo está pensado para tener el código en un mismo archivo `PHP`
>   , sí desea tener en dos archivos quizá sea necesario emplear `Ajax`

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia, el código iría en el mismo index,php ??  o debo crear aparte un archivo php con esas lineas de codigo,?

Comment: En el mismo _index.php_ , si tiene dudas o presenta problemas no dude en comentar.